# Access SharePoint 2013 onpremise REST APIs using NTLM V2

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, ntlm, ntlmv2

I have configured NTLM & NTLM V2 authentication for SharePoint 2013 onpremise.

For **NTLM** auth, I am trying to consume REST APIs via [httpntlm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/httpntlm) and it is working as expected with a successful response.
However, the `httpntlm` not working with **NTLM V2** and getting error as  `Unauthorized 401`.

I also tried [ntlm-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ntlm-client) which supports NTLM and NTLM V2 but not working and throwing an internal unexpected error.

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): 
Error: The server didnt respond properly: Error: Invalid message signature: NTLM

at Object.decodeType2Message (..\node-ntlm-client\lib\ntlm.js:85:9)
at sendRequest (..\node-ntlm-client\lib\ntlmrequest.js:98:28)
```

I have followed [setup-ntlm-v2](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/034b85cd-0900-4326-a416-da9ee568c8b2/setup-ntlm-v2-for-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointgeneral) to setup NTLM V2 in my SharePoint 2013 system.
please suggest.